# In laravel 5.7, i want to show my record from database in View random, but daily or monthly shuffle

Tags: laravel, random, eloquent, sql-order-by, shuffle

I am showing records from my database in my View.

But I want to show it in random order.
And also I want this random order to be changed daily or weekly frequency.

Working on Laravel 5.7 please help me.

I think
`myModel::inRandomOrder->get();`
is the solution.

**But how can i shuffle it weekly or daily.**

**Automatic shuffle is posible here?**

Comment: The eloquent ORM is going to retrieve the collection in random order in every request. So, I don't get what you meant by weekly and daily shuffling on random list?

Answer (score 0):

Happy New Year

I think i can help you with that, You need to store your results in cache for the time period you want and change it accordingly to your time.
You can used the given code example

```
if (Cache::has('cache_date')){
        if (date('Y-m-d') > Cache::get('cache_date')) {
            Cache::forget('cache_date');
            Cache::forget('random_results');
            $values = \App\Models\Technologies::inRandomOrder()->get();
            $date   = date('Y-m-d');
            Cache::put('cache_date', $date);
            Cache::put('random_results', $values);
            return $values;
        }
        else{
            $values = Cache::get('random_results');
            return $values;
        }
    } else {
        $values = \App\Models\Technologies::inRandomOrder()->get();
        $date   = date('Y-m-d');
        Cache::put('cache_date', $date);
        Cache::put('random_results', $values);
        return $values;
    }
```

also don't forget to use Cache class in top of your controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can precise `seed` in `inRandomOrder()` method.

`seed` will allow to have the same random result according to the value.

So you can just use :

```
// $daily will be unique every day
$daily = date('Ymd');

myModel::inRandomOrder($daily)->get();
```